# ¿Se puede enviar un correo automáticamente sin entrar a la página web?

Tags: php, phpmailer

Estoy haciendo un pequeño sistema que me envía correo cada vez que yo doy clic en enviar, después de llenar un formulario. Me lo envía con correo de Gmail, y este envío lo hago con AJAX y PHPmailer.

¿Se puede enviar automáticamente un correo cuando llegue una fecha específica? Es decir, si establezco en la base de datos un día y ese día cae, por ejemplo, en domingo o sábado, ¿el sistema puede enviar un correo automáticamente en base a la fecha definida?

Comment: Encontré esta información, espero que te pueda ayudar
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36699030/add-date-to-attachment-in-php-mailer-smtp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una manera de hacerlo sería programar una tarea cron que ejecute el script que te manda el correo sin necesidad de ninguna interacción por tu parte.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer eso ejecutando una tarea automatizada en el servidor donde se aloja la aplicación, la tarea debe ejecutar el script php en donde tienes el código para enviar el correo, si es un servidor linux entonces un ejemplo sería el siguiente:

```
0 0 * * * php /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/scripts/example.php
```

[Referencia en de CRON (tareas automatizadas) en inglés](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)